# Javascript validating a regex differently than

Tags: javascript, regex

**This JavaScript commands:**

```
var emailPattern = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+$");
var res = emailPattern.test("email@.com")
console.log(res); // true
```

Validates to true. I believe my regex specifies, that the text after the '@' sign must contain one character (one of: a-zA-Z0-9_.-) plus another '.' and some other alphabetic characters.

When I run this **same regex** on http://regexr.com/, my beliefs are met :)

**Why is there a difference, please?**

Thanks a lot.

[image]
A depiction of the regex not validatin email@.com

Comment: All correct, but either double the backslashes, or use a regex literal - [`var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+$/;`](https://regex101.com/r/VwnSqc/2).

Comment: Helped, thanks a lot